# The use of xtmixed with the quickicc command

Tags: mixed-model, stata, repeatability

I am attempting to do a icc using the `quickicc` command following the use of `xtmixed`. I'm attempting to check repeatability in a sample of 24 individuals with QT measures (a measure of ventricular depolarization).  Each individual has various readings of QT; some have 31 whilst others have 5 measured at various times by one reader. My question: is it possible to do an analysis using the `xtmixed` command when obs vary in numbers when testing test-retest reliability or is it even appropriate? Furthermore, I'm unclear if I am using the commands properly as when I use the command `xtmixed qt || study_id:` I get a iteration string that goes on endlessly.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to the site. If you are getting stuck with the log-likelihood, it means your model is not identified. Although nothing can be simpler than your model (which is in fact a random effect ANOVA model, so you could have started from `anova` or `xtreg, re` just as well).

Answer (score 1):

Your question was answered by Clyde Schechter on [statalist](http://stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-02/msg00670.html). He suggested using `xtreg, re` instead, and interpret the reported fraction of the residual variance due to the random effect as the ICC you are looking for.

Comment: The ICC = `e(rho)` after `xtreg`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ICC using xtmixed is as follows
Downoad and install the package ICCVAR using findit

Data should be in long form with at least three variables, one for the dependent variable, one for assessor (iteration in your case), and an id variable to denote individual subjects.

xtmixed scorevariable assessorvariable || idvariable: 
quickicc

The model below assumes that there is a specific errot associated with each assessor but you have only one assessor. I would suggest that you should can set up a hierarchical model and estimate the variance using some software (a SEM program would do) or WinBUGS and get the ICC by hand using the formula

Variance between subjects / Total Variance

where total variance is the sum of the three variances (between subjects, between observers, error variance)